# Low Freeform Database Error

Tags: add-on, ee2, solspace-freeform

When trying to publish to a channel with the the Low Freeform fields I’m getting the following error. ( example: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-freeform-field/docs#example )

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT name, label FROM exp_freeform_fields ORDER BY field_order ASC
>
> Filename: third_party/low_freeform_field/ft.low_freeform_field.php
>
> Line Number: 66

On the solspace support forum I found this:
http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/13184/#54340

But I'm looking for a quick fix, instead of having to create all my forms from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working:

In third_party/low_freeform_field/**ft.low_freeform_field.php at line 66**, change the query to:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT field_name, field_label FROM exp_freeform_fields");
```

**at line 72**, change this line:

```
$options[$row['field_name']] = $row['field_label'];
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Low Freeform Field isn't compatible with FF4 (yet), so a quick fix is hard.

You could either look up where FF4 stores its field data (obviously not in `exp_freeform_fields` anymore) and use that in the query inside ft.low_freeform_field.php. Or use FF3 if you must use LFFF.

Comment: changed the query to "SELECT field_name, field_label FROM exp_freeform_fields" and it works great.